# Store multiple TcpClient Connections - VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm building an application that can communicate and send commands to game servers. In the gaming world we call this “rcon” for remote console, but in reality it's just a telnet session. After successful authentication, a text command can be issued to the server and a text response is sent back to the client.

Often times server admins/owners run multiple game servers and every server has its own distinct ip address, port & password. I would like my application to loop through a list/array/datatable/dictionary (or whatever method is best ) of servers, connect and authenticate to each server, then somehow store that connection so commands can be sent to it in the future (Without having to connect & authenticate again)

Below is the code I have that works for a single server. I store the TcpClient(client) & NetworkStream(stm) as global objects which keeps the connection/session open to the server. What is the best method for me to do this with multiple servers since each server will have it's own TcpClient & NetworkStream?

Is there some way for me to store each TcpClient(client) & NetworkStream(stm) in an array, dictionary or something? I'm completely lost with how to approach this.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Public client As TcpClient
    Public stm As NetworkStream

    Sub SendCmd(cmd As String)
        Dim data
        If cmd.Trim = "" Then
            data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(cmd)
        Else
            data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(cmd & vbCrLf)
        End If

        stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim resp As Byte() = New Byte(512) {}
        Dim memStream = New MemoryStream()
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        Dim bytes As Integer = 0
        If stm.DataAvailable Then
            Do
                Thread.Sleep(10)
                bytes = stm.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length)

                memStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes)
            Loop While stm.DataAvailable
            Dim responsedata As String = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(memStream.ToArray())

            If responsedata.Contains("### Digest seed: ") Then
                'The server is asking for authentication: Login to the server now
                Authenticate(responsedata)
            End If
            OutputRTB.Text &= responsedata
        End If
        memStream.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub GetPlayerList()
        If stm.CanRead Then
            Dim data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("bf2cc pl" & vbCrLf)


            Dim PlayerDT As New DataTable
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("PlayerSlot", GetType(Integer))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("HeroName", GetType(String))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("Score", GetType(String))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("HeroID", GetType(String))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("PlayerID", GetType(String))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("Level", GetType(Integer))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("Class", GetType(String))
            PlayerDT.Columns.Add("Ping", GetType(Integer))


            stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            Dim resp As Byte() = New Byte(512) {}
            Dim memStream = New MemoryStream()
            Thread.Sleep(500)
            Dim bytes As Integer = 0
            If stm.DataAvailable Then
                Do
                    Thread.Sleep(10)
                    bytes = stm.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length)

                    memStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes)
                Loop While stm.DataAvailable
                Dim responsedata As String = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(memStream.ToArray())

                If responsedata.Contains("### Digest seed: ") Then
                    'Login to the server
                    Authenticate(responsedata)
                End If
                OutputRTB.Text = responsedata.Replace(vbTab, "^")


                Dim Rows() As String = responsedata.Split(Environment.NewLine)
                For i = 0 To Rows.Length - 1
                    Dim Cols() As String = Rows(i).Split(vbTab)
                    If Cols.Length > 40 Then
                        PlayerDT.Rows.Add(Cols(0).ToString(), Cols(1).ToString(), Cols(37).ToString(), Cols(10).ToString(), Cols(47).ToString(), Cols(39).ToString(), Cols(34).ToString(), Cols(3).ToString)
                    End If
                Next


            End If
            DataGridView1.DataSource = PlayerDT
            DataGridView1.Update()

            memStream.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub Authenticate(ByVal rdata As String)
        Dim DigestKeyStart As Integer = rdata.LastIndexOf(":") + 2
        Dim DigestKeyLen As Integer = 16

        Dim PWResponse As String = rdata.Substring(DigestKeyStart, DigestKeyLen) & PassTXT.Text
        PWResponse = "login " & GenerateHash(PWResponse)
        SendCmd(PWResponse)
    End Sub

    Private Function GenerateHash(ByVal SourceText As String) As String
        Dim objMD5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim arrData() As Byte
        Dim arrHash() As Byte

        ' first convert the string to bytes (using UTF8 encoding for unicode characters)
        arrData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SourceText)

        ' hash contents of this byte array
        arrHash = objMD5.ComputeHash(arrData)

        ' thanks objects
        objMD5 = Nothing

        ' return formatted hash
        Return ByteArrayToString(arrHash)
    End Function

    Private Function ByteArrayToString(ByVal arrInput() As Byte) As String

        Dim strOutput As New System.Text.StringBuilder(arrInput.Length)

        For i As Integer = 0 To arrInput.Length - 1
            strOutput.Append(arrInput(i).ToString("X2"))
        Next

        Return strOutput.ToString().ToLower

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        stm.Close()
        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConnectBTN.Click
        client = New TcpClient(ServerIPTXT.Text, PortTXT.Text)
        stm = client.GetStream()
        SendCmd(CommandTXT.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendCommandBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SendCommandBTN.Click
        SendCmd(CommandTXT.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetPlayerListBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetPlayerListBTN.Click
        GetPlayerList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

BTW This is my first post on stackoverflow, but I have learned so much from this site over the years =)

Comment: Just a note, if you're keeping these connections open be prepared to  reconnect/authenticate anyways. Network issues can cause the connection to die without warning.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was actually expecting this. When I send a command to the server I check to see what the server's response is

Comment: If responsedata.Contains("### Digest seed: ") Then it tries to authenticate to the server again.

Comment: Create a class called Server() to hold both the values together, then keep a List(Of Server) at class level to keep track of them.  You'll also need to use some threading if you want to communicate with more than one server at a time.  It looks like with an OOP approach some of those methods should be instance methods of Server().